# Unable to log in to chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, login

When I try to enter the General chat room, the message "You must be [logged in](https://askubuntu.com/users/login?returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fchat.askubuntu.com%2frooms%2f3%2fgeneral) to talk" is displayed.

Clicking "logged in" takes me to a page titled "Change OpenID" which lists OpenID providers. When I click one, I get the message "You are currently logged in. Do you want to log out and log in with this OpenID?". I then click the "Log in" button and am taken back to the chat room, which still displays "You must be [logged in](https://askubuntu.com/users/login?returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fchat.askubuntu.com%2frooms%2f3%2fgeneral) to talk".

This happened using Google Chrome 8.0.552.224 and Firefox 3.6.13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to an error made in part (accidentally) buy the StackOverflow Team. [They have fixed this already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73405/why-has-askubuntu-disappeared-from-the-stack-exchange-sites/73411#73411) and it should be resolving properly within the next 24 hours.